# Member's profile grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, grid

I have members site where each of the members can upload a profile picture. Where should I begin if I want to display a grid with all the members' profile pictures and their names (in tooltip style) on a mouse over?
[Here](https://www.thetalentmanager.co.uk/) is an example of what I want to achieve half way down the page on the left) but I'm not sure where to begin. I suspect I need to look into javascript / jquery but I'm not sure where to start. Can anyone offer some advice? Thanks in advance.

Many thanks.

Comment: "_I suspect I need to look into javascript / jquery_". I think that would be good. Try http://learn.jquery.com.

Answer (score 0):

look into jquery

you are going to look into hover
you are going to give the member profile element and id ('smith') or whatever.

the jquery will look something vaguely like this

```
 $('#smith').hover(function()
 {
    $('#profileInfo').html(//whatever stuff you want to show);  

 }
```

you will have an empty element as well call it 'profileInfo'

remember every element that has an id, the id must be unique.